# Haskell typeclasses with algebraic data types

Tags: haskell, typeclass, algebraic-data-types

I have some algebraic data types A, B, and C each implements the class:

```
class Dog a where
   dog :: a -> Bool
```

If I create a new algebraic data type:

```
data D = A | B | C
```

Is there an easy way to have D implement Dog without having to redefine each instance for A, B and C again?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean create a new data type that *uses* the originals? Or combining the existing types into a single type that replaces them? Although, the answer is probably "no, not really" in either case. :T

Comment: How does Dog relate to D? What exactly are you trying to do?

dog :: D -> Bool
dog A = True
dog B = False

Something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before answering, I should point out that you may be falling into a common beginner's misconception about ADT's. Remember, Haskell has two separate namespaces for the type and term levels. So if we write:

```
data A = Foo
data B = Bar
data C = Baz
data D = A | B | C
```

...then there's no connection between the type `A` and the constructor `A` of type `D`. Therefore I suspect (but am not totally sure!) that the question you *meant* to ask had the following format for type `D`, instead:

```
data D = A A | B B | C C
```

In this case, the short answer is "no". You might wish that you could tack on a `deriving Dog` or some such thing and be done, but that facility is not provided by the language. That said, there are some packages for generic programming that could help: just check the Hackage packages list and search for "deriv" and you'll get about ten hits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the correct assumption. That's exactly what I wanted to know.